# Close modal window on redirection. No, not redirecting on closing

Tags: javascript, redirect, modal-dialog

Redirecting on closing a modal window is a common thing. But I am in a little different situation. I want it the other way!.

From my page, I am loading a different website n a modal window. When the user completes an action, the other site will redirect to one URL I passed as parameter to it. But the redirect happens within the modal window. My question is, how do I make  the redirection to happen in main browser window instead in model window? If this sounds impossible, is there any way to detect the redirection event in the model window so that I can close it and get the redirected URL in the main browser window?

The redirected URL will contain few parameters. It is important for me to get these values in parent window.

Answer (score 0):

`window.opener` refering to the parent window

so

> window.opener.location.href = 'new url';

Comment: If I have to use this code it should be in the site opened inside the window. But it is a third party site where I don't have any control

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a URL to the other site in order to redirect the user after he/she completes an action there. So you can pass the URL of a temporary page in your application that its main functionality is to have a handler for `onload` event. This handler can access the main browser window through `window.opener` and give it all parameters received through URL redirection. So the source of the temporary page would be something like this:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadURLinParentWindow(){
            window.opener.href = "http://mainurl/" + window.location.search;
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
<body onload="loadURLinParentWindow()">
</body>
</html>
```

The `window.location.search` at the end of the URL, contains all parameters received from other application (if they are passing them to you in query string).